# What is the limitation of file name/path length for Windows and AIX Server?

Tags: windows-7, filenames, aix, maxlength

Recently I have some files that needed to be copied from AIX server to Windows, However, after I copied the files error appears. It seems that the maximum length of file name/path for these two systems are different.
I have tried Google it and I found many different answers so I don't know which one is correct.

Is anyone know the maximum length of file name/file path for Windows and AIX Server? And is there any different for Windows 32-bit and 64-bit?

I am using Windows 7 and AIX version 6.1.7.15, Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I know that on AIX4.3 the max length of the filenames is 255 characters, this is a limitation within a ufs filesytstems. I don't recall it changing any more than that but I will double check within IBM. Also take note that this is imposed by the fact that AIX4.3 was a jfs filesystem which has a limit of 255 characters, I'll see what I can find about jfs2.

Further checks show that jfs2 max characters is 255 same as jfs.